# PHP 5.4 (5.4.15) VC9 x86 Thread Safe Call to undefined function curl_init()

Tags: php, curl

i configure PHP 5.4 (5.4.15) VC9 x86 thread safe with apache 2.2 all is well except curl extension, i try all setting in php.ini file like 
enabling extension=php_curl.dll 
and defining extension_dir path
but still not work. 
all other extension is working but some thing wrong with curl extension.
I also try this [Fixed curl extensions]http://www.anindya.com/ but this also not solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

After try many version of php i found in php 5.3.25 curl is working fine. but dl() function is not available in this aspi.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the `dl()` function by adding the lines below into your `php.ini` file:

```
; Whether or not to enable the dl() function.  The dl() function does NOT work
; properly in multithreaded servers, such as IIS or Zeus, and is automatically
; disabled on them.
; http://php.net/enable-dl
enable_dl = On
```